# Normal Subgroups in Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I am quite confused about the Group Theory. In particular, would like to ask whether is this statement true.

If $G$ is a group, and $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $|H| |G/H| = |G|$

Thanks! Also, how does normal subgroups link with quotient groups?

Comment: For your first question: yes. For your second question: look up "the first isomorphism theorem". It essentially says that normal subgroups and quotient groups are "dual" to one another.

Comment: @TQFT: Please do not bump a 7 year old question just so you can get some points for minor editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first statement true. The reason is because each element of $G/H$ is a coset of $H$ of the form $g+H$ and so each element consists of  $|H|$ elements of $G$. AS every element of $G$ is in exactly one coset, we have $|G/H| = |G| / |H|$, which gives your formula.

As for your second statement, it is not entirely clear what you are asking. Note that normality is a sufficient and necessary condition for the quotient group to be well-defined - in other words, for operations in the quotient to not depend on which representatives from $H$ are used. So normal subgroups and quotient groups are innately linked.